# Laplacian of a function has the same sign of the function itself

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, poissons-equation

Here is the problem:
Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a connected open set with regular boundary, and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a function such that $tf(t)\geq0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that every solution $u\in C^2(\overline{U})$ of the problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\Delta u=f(u) \hspace{0.1in} \text{in } U \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \hat{n}} = 0\hspace{0.1in} \text{in } \partial U
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Is necessarily constant, where $\hat{n}$ denotes the unitary normal to $\partial U$. Furthermore, state an additional condition on $f$ that guarantees that $u$ vanishes identically on $U$.

My idea was to use the Divergence Theorem, which in this case implies that:

\begin{equation}
\int_U \Delta u = \int_{\partial U} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \hat{n}} = 0
\end{equation}

Hence:

\begin{equation}
\int_U f\circ u = 0
\end{equation}

Now, the condition on $f$ just means that $f(t)$ has the same sign as $t$, and at $0$ continuity might fail. And, since $U$ is connected, if $u$ is not constant, it assumes every value between each two distinct values it assumes.

I tried to use these facts to get a contradiction with the vanishing of the last integral, but I got stuck. Any help or hints are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume your $\Delta$ takes the sign convention $\operatorname{div}\circ\operatorname{grad}$ rather than $-\operatorname{div}\circ\operatorname{grad}$.

By Green's first identity/Divergence theorem/...,
$$
\int_U (\underbrace{u\Delta u}_{=uf(u)\geq 0}+\underbrace{\lvert\nabla u\rvert^2}_{\geq 0})=\int_U\nabla\cdot(u\nabla u)=\int_{\partial U}u\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0,
$$
so we must have $\nabla u=0$ on $U$.  Can you see how to finish this and do the second part?

Comment: Ok, comparing the first integral with the vanishing of the third one we have that the gradient of $u$ is zero, hence, it is constant on $U$. But it can equal any constant $c$ such that $f(c)=0$.
So, for $u$ to vanish, is it enough to ask that $f^{-1}({0}) = {0}$?

Comment: or $\varnothing$.  In other words, $tf(t)=0$ iff $t=0$.

Comment: Precisely! Thats great, appreciate it!